# Command works, and then doesn't (cd/ls)

Tags: command-line

I'm currently doing my thesis and thus working on a school server. And unfortunately, I'm struggling with even the most basic concepts. Such as this.

I have a directory `/home/myname/Data`

If I'm in `/home`, and use `ls` I don't see the directory `myname`, yet, when I specify `cd myname` it still works and `l` works as well. Can somebody explain why `ls` doesn't work, but `l` does?

Edit: If I'm in `/home`, I do see other directories, but I'm missing a few. I'll check with my supervisor what should be there.

Comment: When you say "I'm in home", do you mean that you're in your home directory, or that you're in the directory above that, called `/home`? Please [edit] your question to make that clear.

Comment: Please execute the command `echo "shell=$SHELL, cdpath=$CDPATH"` and provide the output as part of your question.

Comment: Hi, it is indeed </home> (I didn't know how to create the grey boxes). 
Output is <shell=/bin/bash, cdpath=   >

Comment: Shit, I still don't know how to add the grey boxes. How do I do that?

Comment: `l` or `ll` was often an alias to `ls -la`

Comment: Formatted text goes in backticks ``, which you can apply to selected text with the `{}` option on the menu bar. Please [edit] your question to include the requested information rather than dropping it into the comments - it's too easy for important information to get "lost" there.

Comment: Please explain "I don't see the directory `myname`". Do you see any other directories? (Are there any other directories you'd expect to see?) Does `ls` report an error of any kind or indeed give any output whatsoever?

Comment: If you run this sequence of commands can you see `myname` in the output: `cd ; ls ..` After running that does `pwd` give you `/home/myname`?

Comment: Yes it does! Thanks. 

Rui, thanks for your answer as well!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feels like your home directory is being automounted on demand. This configuration is most frequently used when there are a number of free access workstations. It allows for backups to be taken of files on the central server, and the workstations can be rebuilt at any time from a standard image that has no need to worry about persistent local file storage.

When you access a directory under `/home` it is mounted automatically from a central file server. When you cease using it, the directory is (eventually) unmounted again.

It *is* very confusing, because directories that "aren't there" spring into existence when you try to reference them. Since you're a beginner, all I can really suggest is that you ignore this complexity and concentrate on learning within subdirectories of your home directory (`$HOME`). Good luck.